# Repeating the same action on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got some code for a drop-down infobox and it has some Javascripts attached to it. It works perfectly but I'm now trying to duplicate it for a second box below, but I'm getting a few bugs.

In order to duplicate this, do I just copy and paste the script and HTML and change:

handleClick() **to** handleClick2()

drop_down **to** drop_down2

product_section **to** product_section2

or is there an easier way to attaching the same Javascript to two boxes?

```js
var show = false;

const handleClick = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector(".drop_down");
  const product = document.querySelector(".product_section");

  if (!show) {
    element.innerHTML = `close <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>`;
    product.style.display = "block";
    show = true;
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = `more info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>`;
    product.style.display = "none";
    show = false;
  }
};
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 50px">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ranked">
      <div class="badge_one">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="badge_two">
        <p>16% off</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41HiQaqjI-L.jpg" alt="product" class="product_image" />
    <div class="overview_section">
      <p class="title">
        Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ57EB-K Compact Digital Camera - Black (16 MP, 20x Optical Zoom)
      </p>
      <p class="company">Panasonic</p>
      <a href="#" class="drop_down" onclick="handleClick()">
            More info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="price_section">
      <div class="section_one">
        <p class="price">
          9.9
          <span>
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
              </span>
        </p>
        <div class="btn_block">
          <button class="btn">
                <span class="btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section_two">
        <a href="#" class="info_one"> compare price (2) </a>
        <a href="#" class="info_two"> Buy it on Amazon </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product_section">
    <div class="product_info">
      <p class="heading">product hightlights</p>
      <ul class="features fa-ul">
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span>
                20x optical zoom lens (24-480mm) with 40x intelligent zoom
              </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span> 25p mp4 full hd video recording </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span> 16 megapixel 1/2 33" high sensitivity mos sensor </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span>
                3" 1040k-dot lcd with 180 tilting lcd for self shooting
              </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="heading">
        <span>More deals</span>
      </div>
      <div class="deals">
        <div class="deal_item">
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
          <div class="product_price">
            £165.00
            <small>New</small>
          </div>
          <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="deal_item">
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
          <div class="product_price">
            £165.00
            <small>New</small>
          </div>
          <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
}



.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(78, 137, 175, 0.15);
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ranked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.badge_one {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #00113d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 3;
}
.badge_two {
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #e7cd60;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.product_image {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

.overview_section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 55%;
}

.title {
  color: #8f2e53;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title:hover {
  color: #4a90e2;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


.company {
  color: #001143;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.company:hover {
  color: #4a90e2;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}


.hide { display: none; 

}

.drop_down {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #8f2e53;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.drop_down:hover {
  text-decoration-color: #e7cd60;
}


.price_section {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(78, 137, 175, 0.15);
  width: 30%;
  /* min-width: 130px; */
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.section_one,
.section_two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.price {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #78c02a;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.price span {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.btn_block {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #78c02a;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 18px 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #92e879;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn_label {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info_one {
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: noto sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.info_two {
  color: #17baef;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product_section {
  display: none;
  width: 81vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}



.product_info {
  border-top: 2px solid #e7cd60;
  padding: 25px 50px 25px 70px;
  background-color: #e9f5fd;
}

.heading {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #00113d;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.features {
  color: #00113d !important;
  list-style: none;
}

.feature_item {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feature_item:hover {
  color: #638043;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.feature_item i {
  color: #78c02a;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 25px 0;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.deals {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.deal_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.product_logo {
  max-width: 70px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.product_price {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1.1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.product_price small {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.product_btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #78c02a;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product_btn:hover {
  background: #92e879;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.product_btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 776px) {
  .box {
    width: 90vw;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .ranked {
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
  }

  .product_image {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }

  .company {
    order: -1;
  }

  .price_section {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }

  .section_one {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .section_two {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .info_one {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .info_two {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .btn_block {
    /* width: 40% !important; */
    width: 40vw;
  }

  .btn {
    padding: 9px 30px;
  }

  .overview_section {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  .drop_down {
    width: 90vw;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e9f5fd;
    color: #1f1740;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .product_section {
    width: 93vw;
  }

  

  .product_info {
    padding: 20px 5px;
  }

  .heading {
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .features {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  .feature_item {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .divider {
    margin: 15px 0;
  }

  .deals {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .product_logo {
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .product_price {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .product_btn {
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You never, ever blindly copy functions and attach numbers to their names. Never, ever. The entire point of a function is to not have its content more than once in your code, avoiding precisely that is the only reason why functions exist in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisG OP specifically states '_or is there an easier way to attaching the same Javascript to two boxes_' so I think they already know that, but they don't know how to achieve it...

Comment: @Martin Sure, I just wanted to stress how bad and wrong that approach is and that it should be unlearned immediately.

Comment: Here's how to assign a click handler function to multiple elements: https://jsfiddle.net/yun1e67L/

Comment: @ChrisG I strongly recommend to delegate from the container instead of looping eventListeners https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6xcng8kz/

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, it'll avoid the common trap of newly created elements that do nothing, but is there a downside to adding event listeners to multiple elements other than that?

Comment: There is an overhead of adding and unknown number of event listeners and the trap you mention is big enough to just always delegate. It does no harm at all to delegate so why not.

Comment: no needs of tha, you can simply use The Details disclosure element -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate from the outer container

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("drop_down")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const parent = tgt.closest(".box").parentNode; // or give the <div style="margin-top: 50px"> a class
    const element = parent.querySelector(".drop_down");
    const product = parent.querySelector(".product_section");
    product.classList.toggle("hide")
    element.innerHTML = product.classList.contains("hide") ? `more info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>` :`close <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>`;
  }
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="margin-top: 50px">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="ranked">
        <div class="badge_one">
          <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="badge_two">
          <p>16% off</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41HiQaqjI-L.jpg" alt="product" class="product_image" />
      <div class="overview_section">
        <p class="title">
          Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ57EB-K Compact Digital Camera - Black (16 MP, 20x Optical Zoom)
        </p>
        <p class="company">Panasonic</p>
        <a href="#" class="drop_down">
            More info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="price_section">
        <div class="section_one">
          <p class="price">
            9.9
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
              </span>
          </p>
          <div class="btn_block">
            <button class="btn">
                <span class="btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section_two">
          <a href="#" class="info_one"> compare price (2) </a>
          <a href="#" class="info_two"> Buy it on Amazon </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_section hide">
      <div class="product_info">
        <p class="heading">product hightlights</p>
        <ul class="features fa-ul">
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>
                20x optical zoom lens (24-480mm) with 40x intelligent zoom
              </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span> 25p mp4 full hd video recording </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span> 16 megapixel 1/2 33" high sensitivity mos sensor </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>
                3" 1040k-dot lcd with 180 tilting lcd for self shooting
              </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="heading">
          <span>More deals</span>
        </div>
        <div class="deals">
          <div class="deal_item">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
            <div class="product_price">
              £165.00
              <small>New</small>
            </div>
            <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="deal_item">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
            <div class="product_price">
              £165.00
              <small>New</small>
            </div>
            <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 50px">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="ranked">
        <div class="badge_one">
          <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="badge_two">
          <p>16% off</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41HiQaqjI-L.jpg" alt="product" class="product_image" />
      <div class="overview_section">
        <p class="title">
          Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ57EB-K Compact Digital Camera - Black (16 MP, 20x Optical Zoom)
        </p>
        <p class="company">Panasonic</p>
        <a href="#" class="drop_down">
            More info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="price_section">
        <div class="section_one">
          <p class="price">
            9.9
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
              </span>
          </p>
          <div class="btn_block">
            <button class="btn">
                <span class="btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section_two">
          <a href="#" class="info_one"> compare price (2) </a>
          <a href="#" class="info_two"> Buy it on Amazon </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_section">
      <div class="product_info">
        <p class="heading">product hightlights</p>
        <ul class="features fa-ul">
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>
                20x optical zoom lens (24-480mm) with 40x intelligent zoom
              </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span> 25p mp4 full hd video recording </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span> 16 megapixel 1/2 33" high sensitivity mos sensor </span>
          </li>
          <li class="feature_item">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
            <span>
                3" 1040k-dot lcd with 180 tilting lcd for self shooting
              </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="heading">
          <span>More deals</span>
        </div>
        <div class="deals">
          <div class="deal_item">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
            <div class="product_price">
              £165.00
              <small>New</small>
            </div>
            <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="deal_item">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
            <div class="product_price">
              £165.00
              <small>New</small>
            </div>
            <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm a little confused, where does the ".hide { display:none; }" bit go? with the Javascript?

Comment: I've added it to the Css file but for some reason it doesn't work, any tips?

Comment: You need to add the class to the `<div class="product_section hide">` too

Comment: thank for you help! I've added the CSS above In the post as i think it's conflicting with something? any idea how i can edit this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic concept without the use of inline JavaScript `on*` handlers.

- Use the `::after` pseudo to style your buttons
- Use a *state* class like `.is-active` to style the active button
- Use a *utility* class like `.u-none` to hide the element
- Use `data-*` attribute to store into it the desired target selector
- Use JavaScript [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]')
  .forEach( btn => 
    btn.addEventListener('click', ev =>
      {
      ev.preventDefault()
      const el   = ev.currentTarget
        , target = el.dataset.toggle
        ;
      el.classList.toggle('is-active')
      document.querySelector(target).classList.toggle('u-none')
      }
    )
  )
```

```css
[data-toggle] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-toggle]::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900; /* Needed for Font Awesome to work */
  content: "\f107";
  padding-left: 5px;
}

[data-toggle].is-active::after {
  content: "\f106";
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

<a data-toggle="#product_23">More info</a>
<div id="product_23" class="u-none">Product section.....</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would pass an argument id to handleClick and use it like :
"drop_down"+id and "product_section"+id
and call handleClick(1) or handleClick(2)
you'd have to copy-paste the html though.
I hope it helped ^^

---

## Edit :

I'll try to make it more clear and make it look less like a comment.

---

### Explaination:

My suggestion is to make the `handleClick()` not a function that is unique to one element but make it so that it can depends on multiple elements.

---

### But how?

Well I first changed the `var show = false` (lign 1) to a `var show = []` to make it a set of states instead of a state (one state per element).

I then added an argument named a in the `handleClick()` giving me `const handleClick = (a) => {...}`. This `a` will be the id of the element we want to change.

I then add my `a` to the selected classes:

```
  const element = document.querySelector(".drop_down"+a); 
  const product = document.querySelector(".product_section"+a);
```

I change the classes names and function accordingly to the previous step:

```
<a href="#" class="drop_down drop_down1" onclick="handleClick(1)"> //lign 17
<div class="product_section1"> //lign 41
```

We now change all the `show` to `show[a]` in the javascript file

---

### Conclusion and final code

You'd want to make the href="" so it doesn't go up when you click. So here you go I hope it helped ^^

#### index.html

```
<div style="margin-top: 50px">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="ranked">
      <div class="badge_one">
        <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="badge_two">
        <p>16% off</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41HiQaqjI-L.jpg" alt="product" class="product_image" />
    <div class="overview_section">
      <p class="title">
        Panasonic Lumix DMC-TZ57EB-K Compact Digital Camera - Black (16 MP, 20x Optical Zoom)
      </p>
      <p class="company">Panasonic</p>
      <a href="" class="drop_down1" onclick="handleClick(1)">
            More info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </a>
    </div>
    <div class="price_section">
      <div class="section_one">
        <p class="price">
          9.9
          <span>
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
              </span>
        </p>
        <div class="btn_block">
          <button class="btn">
                <span class="btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section_two">
        <a href="#" class="info_one"> compare price (2) </a>
        <a href="#" class="info_two"> Buy it on Amazon </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product_section product_section1">
    <div class="product_info">
      <p class="heading">product hightlights</p>
      <ul class="features fa-ul">
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span>
                20x optical zoom lens (24-480mm) with 40x intelligent zoom
              </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span> 25p mp4 full hd video recording </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span> 16 megapixel 1/2 33" high sensitivity mos sensor </span>
        </li>
        <li class="feature_item">
          <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
          <span>
                3" 1040k-dot lcd with 180 tilting lcd for self shooting
              </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="heading">
        <span>More deals</span>
      </div>
      <div class="deals">
        <div class="deal_item">
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
          <div class="product_price">
            £165.00
            <small>New</small>
          </div>
          <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="deal_item">
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/comparaboo/partners/amazon.png" alt="company_logo" class="product_logo" />
          <div class="product_price">
            £165.00
            <small>New</small>
          </div>
          <button class="product_btn">
                <span class="product_btn_label">view product</span>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

#### index.js

```
var show = [];

const handleClick = (a) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(".drop_down"+a);
  const product = document.querySelector(".product_section"+a);

  if (!show[a]) {
    element.innerHTML = `close <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>`;
    product.style.display = "block";
    show[a] = true;
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = `more info <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>`;
    product.style.display = "none";
    show[a] = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Why not show actual code in a `[<>]` snippet?

Comment: Could the answer be expanded a little more using code sections (as indicated by @mplungjan) and a better explanation?  There are the roots of a good answer here